# In some devices, JavaScript doesn't work in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I worked with hippo animator software that build animation file with html format.

I put this html file to my project in webview. In some devices, it shows the animation but in some others, it doesn't.

I also writing the settings for webview here:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: On which devices does work or not work?

Comment: it dosnt work in some devices like galaxy ace or experia z.but it works in many devices like galaxy s4,nexus 5 and...

i want to make it works in all devices